# When was the first appearance of the Not-Walter demon?

Tags: goblins-comic

The [Goblins comic for 2/24/2012](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/02242012/) re-introduces a character that I vaguely recall we've met before.  It's a demon whose name Minmax had previously tried to guess, with one attempt being "Walter", but failed.  Thereby, I'm calling him "Not-Walter".

Does anyone remember when it was that we first met him?

Comment: Finally!  A Goblins question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, thanks to @Gilles for the [great starting point](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11930/1639) for this answer.  However, the [comic on 12/03/2005](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/12032005/) is not the *first* appearance of Not-Walter.

The first clue that he'd appeared even earlier was the fiery pit.  It just looked too familiar (as in, I've seen it before *and not just* in this strip) and even Minmax seemed to give a sigh of "Here we go again!" when he heard the rumbling.  Then, Not-Walter appeared and immediately recognized Minmax by saying "It's the little girl again".

Since Goblins only started six months earlier than that strip, and releases only two strips per week, I figured the very first appearance was probably not far from the very beginning of the comic.  Working my way forwards from the start, I first found Not-Walter in [a full-page scene drawn for the 7/17/2005 strip](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/07172005/).

As in his second appearance, Not-Walter has entered our realm at the behest of the Dungeon Master/Deity, Herbert, [in answer to Forgath's Prayer](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/07162005/).  After a brief interlude during which we follow the Goblins' storyline, we find that even this monster must yield to Minmax on the odd occasion that [Minmax wins Initiative](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/07292005/).  And, why does Not-Walter call Minmax "the little girl" anyway?  [Because he cries like one](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/08092005/) before being tossed aside by the demon and then running away ([with a speed of 60](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/08102005/)).

Now though, with the first two appearances having been invoked by Herbert in spiteful responses to prayers, one does wonder what the almighty DM is up to this time.

Answer (score 2):

This daemon [first appeared](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/12032005/) back in book 1 when he rose from the [fiery pit](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/07162005/) to announce that the DM does, in fact, [award roleplaying XP](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/12022005/). A demon [would only serve a mortal who knew the demon's true name](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/12042005/); Minmax tried a few guesses, and [the demon briefly pretended that Walter was a correct guess](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/12052005/) to joke at Minmax's expense.

Comment: Hrm.  That first appearance mentions some previous interaction, and I'm pretty sure there's been at least one other "firey pit" scene which may also have involved this demon.  The links give a good starting point, though.  I'll do some more digging through the archive to see what else it is I'm (mis-?)remembering.