# What would happen if Minmax did not pull Oblivous from its portal?

Tags: goblins-comic

In the [Goblins comic for 3/2/2012](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/03022012/), we see Minmax in his first battle with his new sword which has been named Oblivious.  ([So named](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/02172012/) because it is [made of Oblivion](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/02072012/), and Minmax apparently traded some of his understanding of the English language for some other perks.)  In this battle, we again witness the property of the sword which allows it to always be available to its owner because it is [frozen in space-time whenever they are separated](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/02142012/).

At the time this is effected in this battle, the comic panel shows an interesting scenario which could conceivably have been turned further to Minmax's advantage.  Particularly, I'm looking at this piece:

[image: Minmax, in pink armour and gloves, wearing his brown backpack, is flung backward towards the viewer's left as Not-Walter's sword strikes him with a "CLANG." Not-Walter, massive and red with brown spots and glowing white eyes, follows through on his backhand stroke with his golden sword behind his right shoulder, his left hand clenched low in front of him. Just in front of his arm, future-Minmax reaches through a portal to grab Oblivious.]

Here, it appears that the sword is in a very good position to get a swing in at [Not-Walter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11909/1639).  However, I'm not sure if this just seems so because of the visual effect Thunt has chosen for Oblivious' retrieval, or if it is something that could actually have worked.

While Minmax seems to be reaching into a portal through space-time, from which he withdraws the sword, the situation may actually be a bit different.  I see two possibilities here:

1. What appears as a portal is actually a portal, which lasts until Minmax removes his arm (holding Oblivious) from it.  If this is the case, Minmax would indeed have had an opportunity, had it occurred to him, to take a swing at Not-Walter in the past while he was still holding Oblivious in that position.
2. The portal is merely an illusion created by the momentary transposition of Minmax's arm through space-time as it retrieves Oblivious.  This would mean that, as soon as Oblivious is re-joined with its owner's hand, the sword is instantaneously transported to be with the owner in their current space-time.  Minmax never actually withdraws his arm from, or inserts it into, the portal.  Rather, his arm is momentarily consumed by the portal and then immediately released from it with Oblivious in hand.  Here, he would not have opportunity to take advantage of Oblivious' pre-retrieval position.

Are either of these options correct, or is there a more likely one I'm not considering?

Comment: I don't have the time for references rigth now... but has a Goblins reader I would say it is option 2. The sword doesn't exist except in MinMax hand, so the portal is not something that MinMax uses to get the sword, the portal is created around his arm the moment he tries to reach for the sword.

Answer (score 1):

I vote option 1, because the portal seems to remain for a [moment](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/02142012/) after Minmax removes his hand, and also because sound transmits through it. Thus, if Minmax remembers to give a slice with Oblivious before withdrawing his arm through the portal, he could probably hit something in the past. I think that Thunt has some more to show us about Oblivious' unique nature, so this might even be a plot point soon (I have some guesses as to how Minmax might survive the situation he's [just](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/03082013/) gotten himself into).

Answer (score 0):

I would say 2, because that's what seems to happen when he first drops the sword.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty clear that the answer is "there's no way Minmax could plan something that."  He can't even associate what's happening *now* with Oblivious with what he was doing a second ago:

[image: portion of Goblins comic for 2014/01/11; Minmax keeps trying to throw Oblivious only to immediately grab it out of the air to try again.]

It does appear that he is *drawing* Oblivious from the portal, though, so in *theory* it might be possible for him to do something else with it.  In practice, however, there's no way he could keep track of 2 things at once like that.  Here's a scene of him drawing Oblivious through the portal:

[image: portion of Goblins comic for 2012/03/02; on the left Minmax reaches across his body to his left to reach through to portal for Oblivious, in the right frame he pulls Oblivious across in front of him to block an attack.]